# Git (Windows) - cannot create file on clone. Works as Superuser

Tags: windows, git

I'm using Windows 8, 64bit - I recently installed Git to use it on this computer. However, it is not possible to clone any repository. It exits with the message:

```
$ git clone ssh://me@some.address.com/some/git/repository.git
Cloning into 'repository'...
error: Unable to create c:/Users/Danyel/workspace/repository/.git/HEAD
```

When I open `cmd` as Administrator and try the same command, it succeeds (`cmd` as normal user fails just like with Git Bash):

```
C:\Users\Danyel\workspace>git clone ssh://me@some.address.com/some/git/repository.git
Cloning into 'repository'...
remote: Counting objects: 221, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (195/195), done.
remote: Total 221 (delta 34), reused 167 (delta 15)
Receiving objects: 100% (221/221), 9.23 MiB | 1.38 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (34/34), done.
Checking connectivity... done
```

I'm using this version of Git: `Git-1.8.4-preview20130916`

Any help or clues are welcome! I have checked for the permissions and have ownership in parent folders ("repository", ".git"). What else can it be??

Edit:

The GIT_TRACE option did not give any clue about it either:

```
$ GIT_TRACE=2 git clone ssh://me@some.address.com/some/git/repository.git
trace: built-in: git 'clone' 'ssh://me@some.address.com/some/git/repository.git'
Cloning into 'repository'...
error: Unable to create c:/Users/Danyel/Desktop/repository/.git/HEAD
```

Comment: You could try setting `GIT_TRACE=1`: `GIT_TRACE=1 git clone ssh...` (in git bash or Cygwin bash). That should produce more diagnostics...

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help at all, either. `$ GIT_TRACE=2 git clone ssh://me@some.address.com/some/git/repository.git; trace: built-in: git 'clone' 'ssh://me@some.address.com/some/git/repository.git'; Cloning into 'repository'...; error: Unable to create C:/Users/Danyel/Desktop/repository/.git/HEAD` is all I get.

Comment: did you ever figure this one out? I have the same problem plus 'git init' gives the same error. Oddly, it is able to create the .git folder and get stuff in there.

Answer (score 0):

As illustrated in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/msysgit/uET5B7SPpIY), that kind of error message only happens when one of the parent folders is a symlink.

Check if you can clone it in another path (`C:\` or `C:/Users/Danyel`).

But I suspect that `Desktop\workspace` is a symlink, and as such, not very compatible with a cloned repo path (because that would un-symlink that path, which might not be compatible with other apps/process using that same path).
The only other instance of that issue is related to a [path-length limit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20429966/6309).

Comment: Doesn't have to do with symlink, unforunately: `C:\>git clone ssh://me@some.address.com/some/git/repository.git -> 
Cloning into 'repository'... -> 
error: Unable to create C:/repository/.git/HEAD`

Comment: @Danyel and in `C:\Users\Danyel\` ? And for any other repo like a GitHub one? Does the issue persists for those repos as well?

Comment: For every repository. As I said, as Superuser there is no problem.

Comment: @Danyel and for any repo as well? A GitHub repo would also fail to clone as a regular user?