# error: git checkout-index: unable to create file (Permission denied)

Tags: git, permissions, pull

When I try and pull from github I get a strange error. Can I bypass this or force it? I have used sudo before which I suspect would work however this caused other problems.

Comment: Do you have write permission in the directory from where you ran `git clone`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209902/git-checkout-and-reset-on-windows-occasionally-shows-random-files-have-changed doesn't help?

Comment: @VonC: Since he mentions sudo he probably works under Linux or OS X.

Comment: @honk good point. Then your permission issue is certainly closer to the mark.

Comment: You probably don't want to use sudo in connection with Git in your own development environment.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem as well. I solved it by changing the ownership of the directories to the user I was trying to git pull with:

```
sudo chown -R anthony:anthony *
```

I ran that at the root of my git tracked directory to make sure all the files were owned by the correct user.

Answer (score 4):

In my case it was having sublime text open with the git controlled directory added as a folder in the sublime project. After closing sublime I was able to switch branches without a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! In my case it was webstorm that caused this issue