# msys git causing "fatal: Unable to create 'c:/xxx/.git/refs/remotes/origin/"failed-to-sent".lock ': Invalid argument" error

Tags: git, msysgit

I have `git version 1.9.5.msysgit.0` installed with proper configuration but still getting this error while pulling code?

I tried `git pull` on `develop` branch

```
fatal: Unable to create 'c:/xxxx/.git/refs/remotes/origin/"failed-to-sent".lock
': Invalid argument
Unexpected end of command stream
```

But when I do `git pull origin develop`, everything is fine.

Any thoughts , why ?

Comment: Have a look at [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13065572/git-pull-errors).

Comment: What `does git branch -avv` return?

Comment: @VonC :- it's showing many branches. I think merged branches in develop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quote character isn't a valid file path for Windows; you have named your origin `"failed-to-sent"` (presumably instead of `failed-to-sent`) and as such the Git command won't be able to save any files associated with that origin. You can fix this with a `git origin --rename` command, or you can just edit the `.git/config` file to fix the typo in there instead.

Answer (score 1):

DELETE THAT BRANCH -> git push origin --delete \"failed-to-sent\"